# How to create function that add numbers in array using "while" loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, while-loop

I have an exercise to create a function (lets call it "iterateAndSum") which will sum all numbers in array and return the result. I can't use `reduce` (which is easier). I have to focus on using `while` loop.

I tried and failed miserably:

```
function iterateAndSum(arr) {
    while (i--) {
        e += arr[i]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function iterateAndSum(arr) {
  let i = 0;
  let e = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    e += arr[i];
    i++;
  }
  return e;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But i can not use reduce,  i have to focus on a "while" loop. Is anyway to do so?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
let i = 0;
let sum = 0;
while(i<arr.length) {
  sum+=arr[i];
  i++;
}

//sum = 6
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function iterateAndSum(arr) {
  let e = 0,i=0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
      e += arr[i++]; 
  }
  return e
}

let result = iterateAndSum([5,9,6,2,8,0,4])

console.log(result)
```